# Getting water out of the canoe!

Tags: transparency

I have a canoe(s) in my scene. The water is represented by a low poly plane. Of course when the canoe is in the water the plane cuts into the interior of the canoe. How can I organise to have it where there is no water in the canoe. I couldn't find anything on youtube. Just point me in the right direction. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a Boolean Modifier to the plane, and use the canoe as the object, selecting Difference mode

[image]

Here's an example: [image]